# How to rip WAV audio stream from MP4 stream in C#

Tags: c#, audio, directshow, wav, mp4

Is there any way to rip the audio out of an MP4 stream (or file) in the form of WAV *without the use of 3rd party software* (only using Windows API) in C# code?

I have looked around and the majority of answers revolve around FFMPEG however I must avoid 3rd party software. I tried dabbling in the DirectShow API but I am not sure that will get the audio stream rip I am looking for (if anyone has successfully done it in DirectShow could you provide steps). I would prefer the output to have the WAV headers and such. Maybe rip to MP3 format and convert to WAV?

Thank you for your help and suggestions

Comment: To interface to DirectShow from C# you will - for most of the tasks - need DriectShow.NET open source library. In Windows 7 and later you can use Media Foundation API to read and decode MP4 files (should be doable in C#).

Comment: I'm looking at the Media Foundation API right now. This seems like a viable solution, Thank you. I do have to write a wrapper class / interop in C# correct?

Comment: There is [`Media Foundation .NET`](http://mfnet.sourceforge.net/) however you might want to choose to write your own wrapper. Interfaces are less tricky compared to DirectShow.